# Error Trap SQL Statement Linked Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-list

I am using SQL2008R2 and have a large stored procedure containing a section of SQL that INSERTS a record to a LINKED server (also SQL2008R2). I want to be able to continue on with the stored procedure if the linked server happens to be down, unavailable, etc.

What would be the best way to to do this?  Could an example be provided?

```
IF @InsertToLinkServer = 1
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [Server].[Database].[dbo].[Table]
(field1) VALUES (value1)
END

ContinueHereifFailed:
Other sql statements....
```

Comment: Which RDBMS and version? SQL Server? I think you'll want to search for the try/catch equivalent or exception handling for your RDBMS.

Comment: i editted my post. I tried the TRY...CATCH, but it still did not resume with the rest of the statements.

Comment: Similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503607/try-catch-with-linked-server-in-sql-server-2005-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Try to use dynamic sql wrapped in the TRY/CATCH block

```
DECLARE @dsql nvarchar(max)        
BEGIN TRY
  SET @dsql = 'INSERT [Server].[Database].[dbo].[Table](field1) VALUES (value1)'
  EXEC sp_executesql @dsql
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH  
  PRINT 'Error'  
END CATCH
```