# Why are exceptions not propogated when using linked servers for the outer and inner stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the TSQL below:

```
alter PROCEDURE dbo.InnerStoredProcedure
AS
begin try
declare @result as int
set @result=1/0
end try

begin catch
print 'reached inner catch';

    PRINT @@TRANCOUNT

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

    SELECT 
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, 
               @ErrorSeverity, 
               @ErrorState 
               );
end catch

alter procedure DBO.OuterStoredProcedure
As

go

begin try
exec MyDatabase.DBO.InnerStoredProcedure
end try

begin catch
print 'reached outer catch'
end catch
```

If the two stored procedures are located on the same database server, then both messages are printed to the screen:

```
reached inner catch
reached outer catch
```

However, if the two stored procedures are located on different machines, then 'reached outer catch' is not printed to screen meaning error handling is not working properly.  I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.
I have spent a while Googling this.  For example, I have looked here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36178/linked-server-error-not-caught-by-try-catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Handling Errors in Server-to-Server Remote Stored Procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms191515(v=sql.105))

> RAISERROR and TRY…CATCH
>
> Calling RAISERROR with severity less than 20 from inside a remote
>   stored procedure causes a statement abort error on the remote server.
>   **A TRY…CATCH construct on the local server handles remote batch abort errors only**. If a remote stored procedure calls RAISERROR with
>   severity less than 20 and the remote stored procedure is scoped within
>   a TRY block on the local server, RAISERROR does not cause control to
>   pass to the CATCH block of the TRY…CATCH construct. However, RAISERROR
>   with severity 20 or greater on the remote server breaks the
>   connection, and execution on the local server passes to the CATCH
>   block.

The InnerStoredProcedure does not abort the batch when the error occurs (this also depends on the nature&severity of the error), it continues execution till the end of it and the try/catch of the OuterStoredProcedure does not handle the error (as per documentation).

Options:

```
alter procedure DBO.OuterStoredProcedure
As
begin try
    declare @ret int;
    exec @ret = linksedservername.MyDatabase.DBO.InnerStoredProcedure
    if @ret <> 0
    begin
        raiserror ('proc failed', 16, 1);
    end
end try ...........
```

``

```
alter procedure DBO.OuterStoredProcedure
As
begin try
    --this is not a remote proc call, this is a passthrough query execution (of a proc) at the linked server
    exec ('MyDatabase.DBO.InnerStoredProcedure') at linksedservername;
end try ...........
```

``

```
alter PROCEDURE dbo.InnerStoredProcedure
AS
..............
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, 
               20, ---!!!!
               @ErrorState
               ) WITH LOG;
```

Comment: I followed placks answer here, which is the same as your option two: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503607/try-catch-with-linked-server-in-sql-server-2005-not-working

Comment: Could you also try with THROW (instead of raiserror) in the catch block of the InnerStoredProcedure? THROW terminates the batch...